# TF Lite Model - Force Symmetric Filter Weights In Fully Connected Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

As per the new [TensorFlow Lite 8-bit Quantization Specification](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/quantization_spec), all filter weights are now symmetric, meaning their zero point is always 0. I have a custom subclassed model which I am trying to convert to a TF Lite model, but one of my filter weight matrices for a Fully Connected layer still has a zero point offset. This is not okay because if TF Lite Micro zero-crossings are no longer allowed for INT8. I am unsure of how to remove this offset, or even where to do it. I have tried applying constraints to my Dense layers, such as MinMaxNorm or a custom constraint:

```py
class ZeroMean(tf.keras.constraints.Constraint):
  """Constrains weight tensors to be centered around 0"""

  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def __call__(self, w):
    return w - tf.reduce_mean(w)
```

These did reduce the number of layers which had non-zero zero points, but there is still a single ambiguous weight matrix with `zero_point = 3` . What is the approach to solve this issue? Is it correct to use a constraint for training, or is it a step I should be taking during the conversion into a TF Lite model?

Also, I am having trouble finding which layer it even is... In the output of my TF Lite `interpreter.get_tensor_details()` I see that there are many tensors which have a zero point equal to 3:

```
55.  MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/Tensordot/MatMul;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/BiasAdd;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_3/Tensordot/shape;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/Tensordot;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp/resource
{'dtype': <class 'numpy.int8'>,
 'index': 54,
 'name': 'MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/Tensordot/MatMul;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/BiasAdd;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_3/Tensordot/shape;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/Tensordot;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp/resource',
 'quantization': (0.007181247230619192, 3),
 'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                             'scales': array([0.00718125], dtype=float32),
                             'zero_points': array([3], dtype=int32)},
 'shape': array([16, 64], dtype=int32),
 'shape_signature': array([16, 64], dtype=int32),
 'sparsity_parameters': {}}

56.  MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/BiasAdd;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_3/Tensordot/shape;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/Tensordot;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp/resource
{'dtype': <class 'numpy.int8'>,
 'index': 55,
 'name': 'MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/BiasAdd;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_3/Tensordot/shape;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/Tensordot;MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/dense_2/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp/resource',
 'quantization': (0.007181247230619192, 3),
 'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                             'scales': array([0.00718125], dtype=float32),
                             'zero_points': array([3], dtype=int32)},
 'shape': array([ 1, 16, 64], dtype=int32),
 'shape_signature': array([ 1, 16, 64], dtype=int32),
 'sparsity_parameters': {}}

60.  MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/MatMul_19
{'dtype': <class 'numpy.int8'>,
 'index': 59,
 'name': 'MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/MatMul_19',
 'quantization': (0.007181247230619192, 3),
 'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                             'scales': array([0.00718125], dtype=float32),
                             'zero_points': array([3], dtype=int32)},
 'shape': array([ 1, 16, 64], dtype=int32),
 'shape_signature': array([ 1, 16, 64], dtype=int32),
 'sparsity_parameters': {}}

61.  MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/MatMul_110
{'dtype': <class 'numpy.int8'>,
 'index': 60,
 'name': 'MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/MatMul_110',
 'quantization': (0.007181247230619192, 3),
 'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                             'scales': array([0.00718125], dtype=float32),
                             'zero_points': array([3], dtype=int32)},
 'shape': array([16, 64], dtype=int32),
 'shape_signature': array([16, 64], dtype=int32),
 'sparsity_parameters': {}}

62.  MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/MatMul_111
{'dtype': <class 'numpy.int8'>,
 'index': 61,
 'name': 'MyModel/EncoderLayer/custom_subclass/MatMul_111',
 'quantization': (0.007181247230619192, 3),
 'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
                             'scales': array([0.00718125], dtype=float32),
                             'zero_points': array([3], dtype=int32)},
 'shape': array([64, 16], dtype=int32),
 'shape_signature': array([64, 16], dtype=int32),
 'sparsity_parameters': {}}
```

Given just this information, I'm having trouble tracking down which layers of my model these tensors correspond to. I can see that the issue is in my `dense_2` layer, but I've applied a constraint to this layer and still see an offset.